# Swift Firestore Query through Object Keys

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Firestore as my iOS apps backend.

I have a structure like so...

```
/users
     /userId
           name:"Bob"
           /likedPosts  //this is the object, not a collection
                "post1":true
                "post2":true
```

As a result - I'm trying to display the 'likedPosts' (Post class) on the user's profile.

I can't figure out how to query the results to get the users likedPosts and then query to display each post.

```
func getUserNameAndInfo() {
    if let user = Auth.auth().currentUser {
        // User is signed in

        // References to firebase
        let userFS = Firestore.firestore().collection("users")

        // Set the navigation title to users name
        userFS.document(user.uid).getDocument { (document, error) in
            if let userInfo = document {
                let firstName = userInfo["firstName"] as! String
                let lastName = userInfo["lastName"] as! String
                let likedPostsDictionary = userInfo.data()["likedPosts"] as! NSDictionary
                for (postId, _) in likedPostsDictionary {
                    self.userLikedPostsArray.append(postId as! String)
                    print(self.userLikedPostsArray)
                }

            } else {
                print("User name does not exist")
            }
        }
}
```

So I'm able to get all of the id's for the posts.  But I'm confused as to how I could query Firestore to get the info for these Ids.

Comment: how did you store the data in object from into firestore. I want also store the data in object form like collection/document/collection/doument/invitess1(object) : amount :20,phone number:1234567890..........  can you please tell me how to store that data into firestore

Answer (score 1):

You can keep the user likes in a post and query where the current user's ID is equal to true.

```
/posts
     /postId
           /userLikes
                "user1": true
                "user2": true

let userFS = Firestore.firestore().collection("posts").where("userLikes/\(user.uid)", "===", true);
```

Otherwise using your current structure, you will have to get the data of each post individually. Once you have your array of post keys, you can at least populate some type of list view with empty cells. Then for each of these cells, you must fetch the data for – you can pass on this responsibility to the cell itself, making it render itself once the data for that post has been fetched.

You can retrieve a post document with a post key as follows:

```
let postDocRef = db.collection("posts").document(postId);

postDocRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
    if let document = document {
        print("Document data: \(document.data())")
    } else {
        print("Document does not exist")
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this the only option?  Because my thinking was - I'm having a limited amount of Posts - so say it's 100.  So each User could only have a maximum of 100 liked posts in their document.  However, if I store the userIds on the Post then each post could have hundreds,thousands,millions of userId's!  Kinda makes that document obscenely large

Comment: Well, you can go ahead with your current structure, but you will be required to fetch the info for each post individually. Another option is to fan-out the data of the post into the user's `likedPosts` instead just true – but only the data you need to display the post in a feed for example. If any of this data is mutable and can be changed by the owner, then you will have the job of maintaining every post in a user's liked posts.

Comment: hmmm that fan-out method seems interesting.  Since there is a limited number of posts and these aren't mutable by the user and they're only short text i think this could be a good option.  Will try it out.  Otherwise I think I'd rather fetch each of the posts individually...still unsure how to do that tho